# Overwriting Hover on Twitter-Bootstrap's nav-pills

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a hard time overwriting the hover function on twitter-bootstrap for the nav-pills item. I am using Ruby on Rails

Specifically I want to remove the text-decoration: underline from the hovering

How can i go about doing this? here is the source code:

```
.nav-pills {
 li {
  float: left;

/* Links rendered as pills*/
> a {
  border-radius: $nav-pills-border-radius;
}
+ li {
  margin-left: 2px;
}

// Active state
&.active > a {
  &,
  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    color: $nav-pills-active-link-hover-color;
    background-color: $nav-pills-active-link-hover-bg;
  }
}   } }
```

Comment: Can we have you full code in jsfiddle please.

Comment: JSFiddle could be helpful, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

> Specifically I want to remove the text-decoration: underline from the
>   hovering

May be not the best thing to do (well, why not), but since I can't see your code, try this:

```
.nav-pills > li > a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

or rather:

```
.nav-pills {
    > li > a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}
```

If you post JSFiddle code, I'll edit my answer and give you more precise solution.